# How to manipulate a column conditionally and join on that column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to join tables on a column which I need to manipulate based on a condition of another column.

table1

```
Make SerialNumber Client
AA   0123          1
AA   0124          1
KK   J642          1
ZZ   0444          2
```

table2

```
SerialNumber Color
123           Red
124           Green
J642          Green
0444          Yellow
```

I am very new to SQL, and in the past I have done something like

```sql
Select * RIGHT(RTRIM(SerialNumber),LEN(SerialNumber)-1) from Table1 where Make = 'AA'
```

But now I need something much more involved.

I need to be able to join the two tables based off SerialNumber. Basically, I need to get table1 SerialNumber to look like table2 SerialNumber and join them all in one SQL statement. I do not have the ability to edit tables or create new ones. If the make is AA in the first table I need to remove the first character, which in my case is always zero.

The goal is to have this

```
Make  SerialNumber  Client  Color
AA    123           1       Red
AA    124           1       Green
KK    J642          1       Green
ZZ    0444          2       Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION to handle the two situations of Make:

```
SELECT m.Make,m.SerialNumber,m.Client,c.Color
FROM table1 m
INNER JOIN table2 c
ON m.SerialNumber=c.SerialNumber
WHERE m.Make<>'AA'
UNION ALL
SELECT m.Make,c.SerialNumber,m.Client,c.Color
FROM table1 m
INNER JOIN table2 c
ON RIGHT(m.SerialNumber,LEN(m.SerialNumber) - 1)=c.SerialNumber
WHERE m.Make='AA'
```

Comment: This is good and it does what I need it to do. I was hoping with this info I could finish my problem but I can not. I also need to join 2 more tables to what you have produced. Table3 join on Client and table4 joined on Color. How would I select all variables from those two extra tables and add them to what you have here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading `0`s in the `ON` clause with [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select 
  t1.make, t2.serialnumber, t1.client, t2.color
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on 
case 
  when isnumeric(t1.serialnumber) = 1 
    then substring(t1.serialnumber, patindex('%[^0]%', t1.serialnumber), len(t1.serialnumber)) 
  else t1.serialnumber  
end =
case 
  when isnumeric(t2.serialnumber) = 1 
    then substring(t2.serialnumber, patindex('%[^0]%', t2.serialnumber), len(t2.serialnumber)) 
  else t2.serialnumber  
end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6dd23129eb8919108873c4d2b51001b0).
Results:

```
make | serialnumber | client | color 
:--- | :----------- | -----: | :-----
AA   | 123          |      1 | Red   
AA   | 124          |      1 | Green 
KK   | J642         |      1 | Green 
ZZ   | 0444         |      2 | Yellow
```

Comment: I would ask you the same question I asked above, how then would I go about joining a table3 by client and a table 4 by color to the code you have provided?

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can post a new question.

Comment: Gotcha. Just seemed easier to ask here. Will do.